# Redirect non-www subfolder to www folder

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, joomla3.0

I have just restructured a Joomla 3x website and am also using the JEvents calendar which pulls in details from a Google calendar. The 'bookings-calendar' menu item used to be a child of 'availability-booking' but it has now been promoted to a main menu item.

When a visitor clicks on an event detail, the old link used to be like this:

http://[domain]/availability-booking/bookings-calendar/eventdetail/[eventId]/[eventTitle]

I now need these to redirect - including the www - to:

http://www.[domain]/bookings-calendar/eventdetail/[eventId]/[eventTitle]

I have added the following to the .htaccess file but it doesn't seem to be working:

```
RewriteRule ^availability-booking/bookings-calendar/(.*)$ /bookings-calendar/$1 [L,NC,R=301]
```

I already have a domain-wide non-www to www rule in place before the above RewriteRule, but just in case, I have also tried the RewriteRule like this:

```
RewriteRule ^availability-booking/bookings-calendar/eventdetail/(.*)$ "http://www.[domain]/bookings-calendar/eventdetail/$1" [L,NC,R=301]
```

But neither option works.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely your other www rule has a [L] in it meaning it is the last rule that should be followed.  So if that is above your new rule, it is exiting before reaching it.

Comment: Thanks. I did have [L] in earlier rules, but removing them makes no difference. (In examples I've been trying to copy, almost every rule seems to have [L] after it, even when there are several rules). I still get 404 errors. Does the (.*)$ in the rule allow for any number of sub-directories? If not, perhaps that's the problem. They are dynamically generated by the calendar, so I can't predict what they might be.

Answer (score 0):

I have finally made this work by using "RedirectMatch" instead of "RewriteRule". It works perfectly now.